# VideoView error "Access denied finding property"

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to play a streaming video (600KB) using VideoView. Problem is in some devices there is an error on the logcat:

> ```
> Access denied finding property "media.proxy.enable-wifi"
> Access denied finding property "media.proxy.network.type"
> Access denied finding property "media.proxy.http.addr"
> Access denied finding property "media.proxy.http.port"
> Access denied finding property "media.proxy.username"
> Access denied finding property "media.proxy.password"
> ```

And then a dialog show up telling me that it cannot play the video. Video is an mp4 file accesible from my browser and in some devices it works.

My code is pretty simple:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
videoView.start();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was that the video resolution was to big for the device.

Answer (score 0):

So was the solution to create multiple video files in your storage and request the one fit for the resolution?

Comment: No, I just reduced the resolution of the video.